Did we mean to have motor and motors tags?
I just noticed when adding the motors tag to a question that we also have a motor tag.  Is there some value to having the singular and plural of this word both be tags?  This seems more confusing than useful.  Am I missing something?

Looks like we created a synonym for Motors to motor a few years ago, but we'd not completed the merge.
I've done that now.
